# What to use instead of stop in Rstudio?

Tags: r, function, rstudio

I was wondering if there might be a way thru which when a user enters a **'bad' argument**, my function could send out text in a plot (see my R code below), stop further processing (i.e., ***no OUTPUT be generated other than a message***), **BUT doesn't crash (the way `stop` behaves)?**

As an example, is there a way when `b` is not larger than `a`, only a message be plotted and further processing be stopped without using `stop` which causes the page to crash?

## Here is my R code:

```
 GGG = function(a, b){

 if(b > a) { c = b - a    ## Necessary condition to be met ! 

  } else {

  plot(1, axes = F, ty = 'n', ann = F)  ## Text Message to be plotted 

  text(1, 1, "Unable to process this setting", cex = 2, col = 'red4', font = 2) 

  stop("b must be larger than a" )      ## This just crashes the R studio  

     }

 d =  c / 100     ## this should NOT run in this example because b < a in my example

 return(d)

}

GGG (a = 3, b = 2)  ## b < a, thus function should just plot message
```

Comment: use `warning()` in place of `stop()` to just issue a warning, and move the `d = c / 100` inside the `if / else `. You'll then need to return something in place of `d`

Comment: you can use `return()` to return nothing (`NULL`) from the function

Comment: what do you mean by 'nothing should be passed down' ?, do you mean zero?

Comment: @SymbolixAU, Like in this example `c` never reach the `d = c / 100` so that `d` could e computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `return()` to return "nothing" (i.e., `NULL`) from the function, and use a `warning()` in place of `stop()` so it doesn't 'crash' the function

```
GGG = function(a, b){

    if(b > a) { 
        c = b - a    ## Necessary condition to be met ! 
    } else {

        plot(1, axes = F, ty = 'n', ann = F)  ## Text Message to be plotted 
        text(1, 1, "Unable to process this setting", cex = 2, col = 'red4', font = 2) 
        # warning("b must be larger than a" ) 
        # return()
        return(message("b must be larger than a" ))
    }

    d =  c / 100 

    return(d)
}
```

Comment: I also suggest instead of `warning()` simply use: `return(message("b must be larger than a"))`. At least on my machine warning is not doing anything.

Comment: @parvinkarimi - I've updated the answer with your suggestion to keep it consistent. You can `return` anything you want from the function, you don't even need the `message`, you can just return the string `"b must be larger than a"`